# Second derivative of a function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Geometrically speaking,derivative of a function is the tangent of its curve.If that's so,then what does  the second derivative of that function mean,geometrically?

Comment: Concavity. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_derivative#Concavity

Comment: It is closely related to the curvature (variation of the slope).

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=site:math.stackexchange.com+second+derivative+interpretation

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd Order Derivative helps to find maxima and minima because it determines the change of the curve's shape like is it at top of the curve or at the bottom.
Which is also called concavity.

Answer (score 1):

The second derivative has to do with the concept of [concavity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_derivative). Basically, we have the following:

> If the function $f$ is twice differentiable at $x = c$, then the graph of $f$ is concave **upwards** at $(c,f(c))$ if $f''(c) > 0$ and concave **downward** if$f''(c) < 0$.

Succinctly, from a geometrical point of view, this is how concavity affects the curvature of our original function $f$:

[image]

There are certain parts in our curve where the concavity of the functions changes and we denote these as **inflection points**:

Basically,

> If $f'(c)$ exists *and* $f'(c)$ changes from increasing to decreasing at $x = c$, then the point $(c,f(c))$ is an **inflection point** of the original graph of $f$. Additionally, if $f''(c)$ exists at the inflection point, then $f''(c) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks for catching that typo @user334639.

Answer (score 1):

Just like the first derivative at $c$ tells you how to best approximate the function near $c$ with a straight line, the second derivative (if exists) tells you how to best approximate it by a parabola (possibly degenerate to a line). The first approximation has an error that is "much smaller" than $\Delta x$, and the second one has error much smaller than $(\Delta x)^2$. The difference is that for the first derivative this is necessary and sufficient and for the second derivative it is just sufficient (the function may be well approximated by a parabola near $c$ without having a second derivative there).

The other two answers got my +1 as they give nice intuition for someone who first heard of derivative.

However let me point out that most of what was said is true only assuming that the function has a continuous second derivative, and it equals zero at isolated points or intervals. Otherwise there are nasty examples of functions which have a negative second derivative at $c$ but are not concave on any open interval containing $c$ (concavity *at* $c$ doesn't make sense within the widely accepted definition of the graph lying under chords).